# Triangle on axes in Graphisc3D

Tags: graphics

I was able to plot following figure.

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 36]~Partition~6;
T1 = Triangle[{{1, 0.85}, {7, 0.85}, {7, 0.55}}];
T2 = Triangle[{{0.85, 1}, {0.85, 7}, {0.55, 7}}];
range = Tuples[Range[1, 6], 2];
minMax = {0, 10};
vec = {{0, 0, 165}, {40, 50, 220}, {90, 120, 240}, {140, 180, 
247}, {195, 223, 240}, {230, 227, 230}, {240, 223, 195}, {247, 
180, 140}, {240, 120, 90}, {220, 50, 40}, {164, 0, 0}};
colAll = Blend[RGBColor @@@ (vec/255), Rescale[#, minMax]] &;
data1 = Partition[Thread[{range, Flatten@data}] // Flatten, 3];
Show[Graphics[{colAll[Last[#]], Rectangle[Most[#]]} & /@ data1,   ImageSize -> 300], Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Black, T1, T2}]]
```

which produce the figure below

[image]

Can we add triangles edges of 3D box?

```
data2 = Flatten@
Riffle[Prepend[#, 1] & /@ Tuples[Range[1, 6], 2], data]~Partition~4;
Graphics3D[{colAll[Last[#]], Sphere[Most[#], 0.5]} & /@ data2,ImageSize -> 300]
```

This kind of result is desired

[image]

Comment: For the 3D figure above, triangles are added after pdf file created using adobe illustrator. So I will use it. I don't feel it produces the same effect. But it is not a big deal. Thanks for your try.

Comment: I will try to improve it if you want but please make clear what needs polishing.

Comment: I am especially interested in putting triangles, don't worry about labels. if you make tips of triangles round like 2D case that would be better.

Comment: Please make the question self contained and clear, outline which features are are essential. If triangles are the main issue, there is not need for external data. Round? you mean `EdgeForm@Thick` like in you 2d case? Have you tried to add it and check?

Comment: Yes, adding `EdgeForm@Thick` gives what I want. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data2 = Flatten@
    Riffle[Prepend[#, 1] & /@ Tuples[Range[1, 6], 2], data]~Partition~
   4;
Graphics3D[{
    { colAll[Last[#]], Sphere[Most[#], 0.5]} & /@ data2
  , { FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Dashed
    , Cuboid[Scaled[{0, 0, 0} + .075], Scaled[{1, 1, 1} - .075]]
    }
  , Black
  , Polygon[
   Scaled /@ {{.05, .05, .05}, {.05, .05, .95}, {.05, 0, .95}}]
  , Polygon[
   Scaled /@ {{.05, .05, .05}, {.95, .05, .05}, {.95, 0, .05}}]
  , Polygon[
   Scaled /@ {{.95, .05, .05}, {.95, .95, .05}, {1, .95, .05}}]
  }
 , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]
 , ImageSize -> 300
 , Boxed -> False
 ]
```

[image]